# Android: Do in-app purchases from testphase (Alpha or beta) stay valid new APK for production is released?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

We released an app for testing in open Alpha on google Play.

All in-app purchases could be done, but they were fake (no real money was  transfered).

When we release the app for production, will these in-app purchases (from the alpha stage) keep working?

And also, moving from alpha to beta, will they stay valid?

Comment: in alpha testing if money is not deducted from account it means something is wrong

Comment: you are able to buy in app products from your application??

Comment: You have to change sku string provide to launch purchase 
android.test.purchased change this text

Comment: can you getting purchase Token after purchasing in app product ?

Comment: In-app purchases is working OK. My question is this: Do they stay valid when the app is moved to production.

Comment: All the purchase done in Alpha and Beta release consist order id as blank in purchase response . So basically these are applicable only in Alpha and Beta release only.

Comment: Test purchases, which let your selected license-test users purchase your in-app products without any resulting charges to the user. Test purchases can be used in alpha/beta releases only.

Real purchases, which let regular users make real purchases of your in-app products with actual charges to the user’s payment instruments.